# S3 bucket policy has no effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an IAM user called: GnS.
The user has no policy attached.
and a bucket with a bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1603912432505",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1603912241442",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:user/ADMIN"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1603912431451",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:user/GnS"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
    }
]
```

}

The policy allows Gns user only the following action: s3:PutObject.
Yet when running the next command in the CLI:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket BUCKETNAME --key OBJECTKEY OUTFILENAME
```

I get the object requested.

How can I deny the user from this possibilty?

Comment: The user might be part of some group to which policy is attached. Check inline policies as well. Or SCP in parent account.  Workaround - Try adding explicit DENY policy for all other operations to that user.

Comment: Also check if the bucket has a public ACL or if that OBJECTKEY has a public ACL.

Comment: Clearly the credentials that you used when running `aws s3api` have permission to get objects from that bucket. Check the credentials you used are what you expected (run `aws sts get-caller-identity`) and then check the policies associated with those credentials (including any IAM groups the IAM user belongs to).

Comment: As a test, remove the whole `GnS` part of that policy and see whether you can run the command. If so, something else is granting the permission.